# posting from PHP to ASP page returns raw source code

Tags: php, post, asp-classic

I am trying to post data from PHP to a ASP page. This is the PHP code:

```
$url = 'test.asp';
$data = array('q' => 'test');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { 
  //Handle error
 }

var_dump($result);
```

And this is the ASP page:

```
<%Response.Write(request("q"))%>
```

When I call the PHP page it prints `<%Response.Write(request("q"))%>`. I am testing this structure on IIS with both classic Asp and Php installed.

Comment: _“$url = 'test.asp';”_ - that is a local file system path, and not an HTTP URL. You are not making an HTTP request (which would make the web server get this file parsed/executed), you are just reading the actual _file content_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `test.asp` is, in some contexts, a relative URL, it isn't here.

`file_get_contents` will only make an HTTP request if you pass it an **absolute** URL (e.g. one starting with `http://www.example.com/`).

Passing it a file name will cause it to read from the local filesystem, which bypasses any HTTP server module that would execute the ASP code.